# Javascript : Show div using style.display=' ', but div content only blinks

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

So basically I have this dropdown menu that shows a list of options.
When the first, second, and third option is clicked, it will redirect into a page called products.html, but for each option, the page will show a different content.
Here is the code that I've already done :

HTML

```
<ul class="ul">
  <li><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">PRODUCT</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="products.html" onclick="computerjs()" type="button">COMPUTER</a>
      <a href="products.html" onclick="laptopjs()" type="button">LAPTOP</a>
      <a href="products.html" onclick="smartphonejs()" type="button">SMARTPHONE</a>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li> 
  </li>
</ul>


<div id="content1" style="display: none">
  <font size="16" face="Verdana">Computer</font><br>
  <font face="Verdana" color="gray">Computer technology is constantly changing and top brands are continually launching new computer models. Nano Electronics is here to assist you choose the right computer that best fits your needs and budget.</font>
  <br><br>

  <table width="600 px">
  <tr>
       <td><img src="images/Computer/1.jpg" width="250" height="250" /></td>
       <td width="25 px"></td>
       <td><img src="images/Computer/2.jpg" width="250" height="250" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td align="center"><font face = "Arial" color="gray" size="5">Dell S2317HJ</font></td>
      <td width="25 px"></td>
       <td align="center"><font face = "Arial" color="gray" size="5">HP Pavilion</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td><hr align="left" noshade="noshade" width="250"></td>
       <td width="25 px"></td>
       <td><hr align="left" noshade="noshade" width="250"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td><font face = "Verdana" size="5" color="#272727">$ 320.87</font></td>
      <td width="25 px"></td>
       <td><font face = "Verdana" size="5" color="#272727">$ 620.87</font></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>


<div id="content2" style="display : none">
This will show when I click Laptop.
</div>

<div id="content3" style="display : none">
This will show when I click Smartphone.
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript :

```
function computerjs() {
  document.getElementById('content1').style.display = '';
}

function laptopjs() {
document.getElementById('content2').style.display = '';
}

function smartphonejs() {
document.getElementById('content3').style.display = '';
}
```

With these codes, the div content cannot stay visible and will only blink. 
Can anyone help me with this? Much appreciated.

P.S. I mustn't use JQuery or any type of scripts other than JavaScript.

Comment: Do you define `myFunction` anywhere?

Comment: `href="products.html"` Your page is reloading.

Comment: You'll also want to set the other elements to 'display: none' whenever one of them is clicked if you want them to toggle. (i.e. hide 2 and 3 when 1 is clicked, hide 1 and 3 when 2 is clicked and hide 1 and 2 when 3 is clicked). Otherwise you'll just end up with all of them displaying eventually

Comment: || MikeC - Yes. myFunction() script is used for the dropdown menu system.

|| squint - How should I show the content again after it reloads, then?

|| DibsyJr - Yes, thank you for reminding me.